# Github repo results when using github3.py library

Tags: python, git, github, github3.py

I'm looking through some of the user documentation for github3.py library.

I'm trying to list all of a user's repos.

If I use the code below, with `gr = gh.repos.list().all()`, I get the expected results.

But, if I use `gr = gh.repos.list(user='username',type='all')`, I get this error: `<pygithub3.core.result.smart.Result object at 0x00000000033728D0>`

Looking at the docs, this should work, but I'm new to Python and this library so I may be missing something??

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pygithub3 import Github
import requests

auth = dict(login="xxxx", user = "xxxx", token="xxxxx", repo="my-repo")
gh = Github(**auth)

gr = gh.repos.list().all()

print gr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
from pygithub3 import Github

auth = dict(login="my-github-login", password="my-github-password")
g = Github(**auth)

print g.repos.list(user='user-whose-repos-I-want-to-get').all()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your solution does work, but I'm curious as to why `repos.list` needs `.all()` since, according to the documentation, you should be able to define it with `g.repos.list(user='username',type='all')`

Comment: @DBS
You get
`<pygithub3.core.result.smart.Result object at 0x00000000033728D0>`,
this is not an error. This is how `print` outputs the object returned by call `gh.repos.list(user='username',type='all')`.
Calling `all()` method on that object converts it to Python's `list()` and `print` outputs it in a well-defined standard manner.